# How to color-code columns in MATLAB Clustergram?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, heatmap, axis-labels

I am trying to label specific columns in a MATLAB cluster gram with particular colors to indicate similarities between columns. I am aware of the ColumnGroupMarker function, but I do not want them based on group - I'd like to be able to control whether columns in the same group have different colors, similar to this academic paper:
[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: The [clustergram documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/clustergram.html) has options listed for row/column markers: `set(cgo_all,'RowGroupMarker',rm,'ColumnGroupMarker',cm)`. Is this what you are looking for? It does look like there is only the option for one marker, however. If you want to have two rows of markers, I believe you will have to either (i) create a new set of axes in the same figure and create your own custom function to plot the markers; or (ii) create the markers in a separate figure and then combine them in an image editing program (eg illustrator/inkscape).

Comment: Unfortunately, ColumnGroupMarker only color-codes based on dendrogram clusters. I'm trying to identify individual columns, whether or not they're in the same cluster as other columns. I'll definitely try making a set of new axes!